# DateTime.MinValue in .NET while updating entries in SQL database

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a problem with `DateTime` variable while handling it with `null` value.

In one class, I have:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> BookingDate { get; set; }
```

In another class I have method which uses this variable and convert this variable into null when `BookingDate` is empty, it goes as follows:

```
DateTime bookingDate;

if (!token[2].Equals(""))
{
    bool isBookingDate = DateTime.TryParse(token[2], out bookingDate);

    if (isBookingDate == false)
    {
       throw new Exception("Wrong format in:" + token[2]);
    }
}
else
{
    bookingDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

However, once uploading a file with an empty `DateBooking` column, I am receiving following error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

I know this is related to the min value in SQL Server (`1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM`) and min value in .NET (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`). How can I change this part:

```
else
{
   bookingDate = System.DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

in order to be able to upload a file with an empty `BookingDate`?

Comment: You could write `DBNull.Value` to the database when the date is equal to `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, I would recommend to use **(a)** the `DATE` datatype if you need only the date portion (no time), or **(b)** that you use `DATETIME2` (if you need both date and time) since that datatype doesn't have those issues (min date = 1753-01-01) anymore

Comment: @Andomar I have tried this and it does not work. It says that: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: @marlowe31: yes, you'll have to write it as an `object`, not as a `DateTime`.  Perhaps add the part of the code that writes to the database to your question.

Comment: @marc_s First thing, yes, I need time portion. Second thing, when I change the variable property into DateTime2, Visual Studio does not recognize this.

Comment: @Andomar What do you mean changing it into object? In SQL database, this column type is set to DateTime.

Comment: SQL's `datetime` can contain `null`, but .NET's `DateTime` cannot contain `DBNull.Value`.  Hence you have to pass the lowest common denominator, which is `object`, to the database.

Comment: @Andomar Strange thing is that BookingDate column type in SQL is set to NULL and still it does not allow for nulls.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird.  SQL `null` maps to .NET `DBNull.Value`, not to .NET `null`.  It's probably the worst design decision in the framework.